# Overleaf: How do I add another row in my table?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I have a longtable and I would like that both the first part and the second part of the table are identical. As you can see in the figure, on the first page you have a row "test (total) | test | test | test |Stest | test" . I would also like to see this on the second page (to increase readability of the table)

[image]

`

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for box manipulation
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip} % Used to create spaces between paragraphs
\usepackage{dirtytalk} % quotes by talk
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}  % Used to add a wordlist/glossaries
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%zelf toegevoegd
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow} %table
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pifont} %%%bullet points
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{geometry} %table margin

\begin{longtable}{l|ccc|ccc|}
\caption{test}
\label{test}\\
\cline{2-7}
                     &     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{Duration test}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{test(Count)}}  \\ \hline
                     
  
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{7}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\cline{2-7}
                      &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{Duration test)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{test(Count)}}  \\ \hline
\endhead
%

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test(Total)} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test} &
  {\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test}  &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test} &
  {\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test}  \\ \hline
  

  
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:04}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{07:21}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{47}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:18}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:18}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:40}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{01:20}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{24}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:50}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:16}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:28}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:24}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NOB}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NOB}    
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NOB}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NOB}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{01:53}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{33}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{04:32}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{63}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:05}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test}  
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{13:21}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{128}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:16}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:25}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10:19}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{41}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:26}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:07}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:12}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test}  
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{00:14}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{test} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NOB}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{C}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{D}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{NOB}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{F}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Grand Total}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{43:49}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{43:25}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{48:50}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{401}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{397}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{51}  \\\hline
 \end{longtable}
```

`

I tried to duplicate the following part of the code
`

```
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test(Total)} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test} &
  {\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test}  &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test} &
  {\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test}  \\ \hline
```

`

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre], not just code fragments

Comment: By "add another column", you mean a row?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes! Sorry, I changed the title and will try to make a compatible minimal reproducible example. For now, I just shared the entire table.

Comment: That you shared the entire table is not the problem, the lack of a documentclass and the packages necessary to compile your code are more the problem ...

Comment: Your codes does not compile (no `document` environment) and does not span more than one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the row you want to appear at the top of every page to your longtable header.

Wrapping each and every cell into a `\multicolumn` is neither necessary nor useful for anything.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for box manipulation
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip} % Used to create spaces between paragraphs
\usepackage{dirtytalk} % quotes by talk
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries} % Used to add a wordlist/glossaries
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%zelf toegevoegd
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow} %table
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pifont} %%%bullet points
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{geometry} %table margin
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|ccc|ccc|}
\caption{test}
\label{test}\\
  \cline{2-7}
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{Duration test}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{test(Count)}} \\ \hline
  \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test(Total) & test & test & test & test & test & test\\\hline
\endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
  \cline{2-7}
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{Duration test)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{test(Count)}} \\ \hline
  \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}test(Total) & test & test & test & test & test & test\\\hline
\endhead
%
test & 00:04 & C & D & 1 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 07:21 & C & D & 47 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:18 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:18 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:40 & C & D & 9 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 01:20 & C & D & 24 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:50 & C & D & 7 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:16 & C & D & 2 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:28 & C & D & 7 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:24 & NOB & NOB & 1 & NOB & NOB \\ \hline
test & 01:53 & C & D & 33 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 04:32 & C & D & 63 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:05 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 13:21 & C & D & 128 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:16 & C & D & 4 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:25 & C & D & 6 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 10:19 & C & D & 41 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:26 & C & D & 10 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:07 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:12 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:14 & C & D & 2 & F & G \\ \hline
test & NOB & C & D & NOB & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:04 & C & D & 1 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 07:21 & C & D & 47 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:18 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:18 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:40 & C & D & 9 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 01:20 & C & D & 24 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:50 & C & D & 7 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:16 & C & D & 2 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:28 & C & D & 7 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:24 & NOB & NOB & 1 & NOB & NOB \\ \hline
test & 01:53 & C & D & 33 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 04:32 & C & D & 63 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:05 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 13:21 & C & D & 128 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:16 & C & D & 4 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:25 & C & D & 6 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 10:19 & C & D & 41 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:26 & C & D & 10 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:07 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:12 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:14 & C & D & 2 & F & G \\ \hline
test & NOB & C & D & NOB & F & G \\ \hline 
test & 00:04 & C & D & 1 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 07:21 & C & D & 47 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:18 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:18 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:40 & C & D & 9 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 01:20 & C & D & 24 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:50 & C & D & 7 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:16 & C & D & 2 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:28 & C & D & 7 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:24 & NOB & NOB & 1 & NOB & NOB \\ \hline
test & 01:53 & C & D & 33 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 04:32 & C & D & 63 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:05 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 13:21 & C & D & 128 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:16 & C & D & 4 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:25 & C & D & 6 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 10:19 & C & D & 41 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:26 & C & D & 10 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:07 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:12 & C & D & 3 & F & G \\ \hline
test & 00:14 & C & D & 2 & F & G \\ \hline
test & NOB & C & D & NOB & F & G \\ \hline
\textbf{Grand Total} & 43:49 & 43:25 & 48:50 
& 401 & 397 & 51 \\\hline
 \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```